# Low yearly archives wrong return

Tags: categories, low-yearly-archives

I have 6 entries which should show up, but when i use the code below it gives as return just three results. I think the problem is the **category="not 3"**, does anybody has some experience with the category parameter?

```
{exp:low_yearly_archives 
       channel="agenda" 
       start_month="1" 
       category="not 3" 
       show_expired="yes" 
       show_future_entries="yes" 
       sort="asc" dynamic="off"}

<li><a href="/{year}" data-toggle="tab">{year}
    <span class="badge badge-warning pull-right">{entries_in_year}</span></a>
</li>
{/exp:low_yearly_archives}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [the documentation](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-yearly-archives/docs#tags), the `category` parameter <del>isn't</del> is available in Low Yearly Archives, but isn't documented.

However, the behaviour is the same as the native channel:entries tag, so you could be running into this:

> When you use the category="3|4" parameter (not excluding), you are implicitly telling ExpressionEngine to only deal with entries that have been assigned one or more categories. If you have entries that haven’t been categorized then they will be ignored and not included in the results. However, if you are using exclusion (category="not 3|4"), then you will be shown all entries without those categories including those without any categories assigned.

[See the docs on this.](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#category)

So basically, defining `category="not 3"` will exclude entries that **only** have category 3. If an entry has category 3 **and** another category assigned, it won't be excluded.

Comment: Yeh i saw this later, but it is strange, because without category it returns 6 entries. So it does do something.

Comment: Hah, you're right. Haven't looked at the code in a while. Seems there is a check for categories there. Will have to take a closer look then.